# Two Django projects using same database

Tags: mysql, django

I have a database that is being used by my django project and a php project. So now i am about to add another separate django project which will use the same database.

After setting up the project i wrote models.py and when i tried to run server it is giving error: -

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7fcedb0338c0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
self.check_migrations()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 163, in check_migrations
executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 20, in __init__
self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
self.build_graph()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 299, in build_graph
parent = self.check_key(parent, key[0])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 160, in check_key
raise ValueError("Dependency on app with no migrations: %s" % key[0])
ValueError: Dependency on app with no migrations: apiapp
```

It is not allowing me to run python manage.py migrate.

How to cope up with this type of problem.

Comment: Have you seen: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23366

Answer (score 1):

Make you models and create migrations.
After this run [fake initial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-migrate--fake-initial) migration